# Joomla 3.4 Admin Template Override

Tags: templates, administrator, template-override, joomla-3.4, header

I want to change the header in the default admin template Isis.
This is the output now.

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="container-logo">
        <img src="administrator/templates/isis/images/logo.png" class="logo" alt="sitename">
    </div>
    <div class="container-title">
     <h1 class="page-title">
      <span class="icon-eye thememanager"></span>
      Templatebeheer: Stijlen</h1>
    </div>
</header>
```

I want to have it without:

```
      <span class="icon-eye thememanager"></span>
```

I am not looking for a css method with display:none;.

Somewhere it is coded that an icon is added. I have already looked in the module mod_title in here it shows only php echo $title. So there I could not delete the icons...

I have come close to the effect by changing administrator/includes/toolbar.php but I can't change it in there because it will be lost by an update. I believe. So can I create an override for this. How???

Or is there a better way! Without the CSS display:none because I need to use the span for something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid core hacks, you can use jQuery to remove the `class` attribute:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    $(".icon-eye.thememanager").removeAttr("class");
});
```

This will leave you with only `<span></span>`. If what you're trying to do is change the class rather than removing it (e.g. to change the icon), you can use `.removeClass` and `.addClass`:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    $( ".icon-eye.thememanager" )
          .removeClass( "icon-eye thememanager" )
          .addClass( "icon-anothericon thememanager" );
});
```

The result would be `<span class="icon-anothericon thememanager"></span>`

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going to look into it. I will keep you posted.

Answer (score 2):

The code is located in the following file on line **86**

> administrator\components\com_templates\views\templates\view.html.php

You will see the following code:

```
JToolbarHelper::title(JText::_('COM_TEMPLATES_MANAGER_TEMPLATES'), 'eye thememanager');
```

Please do bare in mind that changing this will be a core hack, so if this file is modified in a future Joomla update, you may lose your changes

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As it is a core hack it cannot be used. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in Joomla 3.4.1, the easiest way in my opinion is to override the css rule for the
`.icon-eye.thememanager:before` selector, using a custom.css inside the ISIS template css folder.

Just create the custom.css file, place it in:

```
administrator/templates/isis/css
```

and add your css override rules for the :before pseudo class.

It can be a `display:none`, or a override over the "`content`" attribute, e.g.:

```
.icon-eye.thememanager:before {content:"";}
```

You are done.

*Keep in mind, that this seems to be a new feature introduced in Joomla 3.4.1. It's unknown yet how this will evolve and what might be the effects of a Joomla update. Just to stay in the safe side, you may want to backup the custom css file before updating.